# How to sync the data google sheet data dynamically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I am fetching the value from particular cell from google sheets using sheets v4 api. In case some one adds new row or column the cell reference is moved below or right.

How can i track these change and sys\nc my local data with correct referenced google sheet value. I tried  `watch_file` webhook but none of them provide the changed valued. they provide only metadata of changes.

https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService.html#watch_file-instance_method

**Note: I have only read access to the file**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the Drive API to manage changes? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes

This will return the metadata of the changes, after which you have to do some calculations on your end to find out where your target range ended up.

An alternative to this would be to create a named range for your target, so when someone changes the sheet structure, your named range will be updated accordingly, and you don't have to use the changes to determine where the range ended up.

**References:**

[Named and protected ranges](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/ranges#add_named_or_protected_ranges)

Comment: this will notify only metadata of change. What i need is the exact change. (i.e) if my pointed cell is moved from A2 to B2. i need to update my db to fetch data from B2 how can i aware of this change?

Comment: Man I just had a look on Named ranges and came back. You also suggesting the same. Seems like a promising solution. Only issue is i need acquire **spreadsheets** scope for API to create named ranges.